# Hibernate - Property being many-to-one and component at the same time?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate, migrating from MyBatis.
I've this Customer bean, which I'm trying to save (INSERT) using the xml mapping. This is a shorter version of my code:

Beans:

```
public class Customer {
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private SystemObject systemObject = new SystemObject();    
}

public class SystemObject {

    private Integer objectId; 
    private Integer userIdCreate; 
    private Integer userIdUpdate; 
    private Date createDate;
    private Date updateDate;    
    private Workspace workspace = new Workspace();    
}

public class Workspace {
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
}
```

As you can see, a Customer has a SystemObject. A SystemObject is a general object, all beans across the code has one. The SystemObject has a Workspace.

The problem is, that the table CUSTOMER, has a reference to OBJECT, and to WORKSPACE **too**. In "objects world", I get the workspace id by doing getSystemObject().getWorkspace().getId(), but I don't know how to do that in Hibernate

Tables (currently on PostgreSQL):

```sql
create table CUSTOMER (
   CUSTOMER_ID          INT4                 not null,
   OBJECT_ID            INT4                 not null,
   WORKSPACE_ID         INT4                 not null,
   CODE                 VARCHAR(100)         not null,
   constraint PK_CUSTOMER primary key (CUSTOMER_ID),
   constraint AK_CUS_CODE unique (WORKSPACE_ID, CODE)
);

create table OBJECT (
   OBJECT_ID            INT4                 not null,
   WORKSPACE_ID         INT4                 not null,
   USER_ID_CREATE       INT4                 not null,
   USER_ID_UPDATE       INT4                 not null,
   CREATE_DATE          DATE                 not null,
   UPDATE_DATE          DATE                 not null,
   constraint PK_OBJECT primary key (OBJECT_ID)
);

create table WORKSPACE (
   WORKSPACE_ID         INT4                 not null,
   CODE                 VARCHAR(100)         not null,
   NAME                 VARCHAR(100)         not null,
   constraint PK_WORKSPACE primary key (WORKSPACE_ID),
   constraint AK_WS_CODE unique (CODE)
);

alter table CUSTOMER
   add constraint FK_CUS_OBJ foreign key (OBJECT_ID)
      references OBJECT (OBJECT_ID)
      on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table CUSTOMER
   add constraint FK_CUS_WS foreign key (WORKSPACE_ID)
      references WORKSPACE (WORKSPACE_ID)
      on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table OBJECT
   add constraint FK_OBJ_WS foreign key (WORKSPACE_ID)
      references WORKSPACE (WORKSPACE_ID)
      on delete restrict on update restrict;
```

And, this is my mapping for the Customer object:

```xml
<class name="ar.com.portal.bean.Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
    <id name="id" column="CUSTOMER_ID" >
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="code" column="CODE" />
    <many-to-one name="systemObject" class="ar.com.framework.base.SystemObject" column="OBJECT_ID" 
            unique="true" not-null="true" lazy="false" cascade="all" ></many-to-one>
</class>
```

Code in main:

```
Session session = HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

Customer anew = new Customer();
anew.setCode("new test");
SystemObjectManager.prepareSystemObject(anew); //this line sets all values for the systemObject inside Customer
anew.getSystemObject().getWorkspace().setId(1);
session.save(anew);
transaction.commit();
```

This way, hibernate tries to insert both objects, Customer and SystemObject, but fails because Customer has null at WORKSPACE_ID column:

(sorry, error is in Spanish)

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: el valor null para la columna «workspace_id» viola la restricción not null   Detail: La fila que falla contiene (3, 8, null, 'new test').
```

Then, I tried this way. Added a getWorkspaceId() in SystemObject (just to try and simplify one step) and changed the mapping to this:

```xml
<class name="ar.com.portal.bean.Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
    <id name="id" column="CUSTOMER_ID" >
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="code" column="CODE" />
    <component name="systemObject" class="ar.com.framework.base.SystemObject" >
        <property name="workspaceId" column="WORKSPACE_ID" />
    </component>
    <many-to-one name="systemObject" class="ar.com.framework.base.SystemObject" column="OBJECT_ID" 
            unique="true" not-null="true" lazy="false" cascade="all" ></many-to-one>        
</class>
```

That doesn't even start:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of systemObject found in ar.com.portal.bean.Customer
```

But I know that could work, because if I delete the "many-to-one", the value for the WORKSPACE_ID column is present in the INSERT statement (but fails for not having an OBJECT_ID)

So... I have this property, that I need it to be a many-to-one relationship and a component at the same time, but Hibernate doesn't like that. There is another way to solve this particular situation? or I've to write a custom insert using a named query?

Answer (score 0):

The bean should be

```
public class Customer {
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private SystemObject systemObject = new SystemObject();    
    private Workspace workspace= new Workspace ();    
}
```

And then the mapping should be

```
<class name="ar.com.portal.bean.Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
    <id name="id" column="CUSTOMER_ID" >
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="code" column="CODE" />
    <component name="workspace" class="ar.com.framework.base.Workspace" >
        <property name="workspaceId" column="WORKSPACE_ID" />
    </component>
    <many-to-one name="systemObject" class="ar.com.framework.base.SystemObject" column="OBJECT_ID" 
            unique="true" not-null="true" lazy="false" cascade="all" ></many-to-one>        
</class>
```

Comment: I don't want to repeat the Workspace object... it is already inside SystemObject. The tables need the FK because there is a UK constraint, but the object doesn't need it. There aren't another way of mapping this situation?

Comment: Then remove **WORKSPACE_ID         INT4                 not null** from your Customer table

Comment: Can't do that... there is an unique constraint using columns **WORKSPACE_ID** and **CODE**